# PrimeFlex not working properly on Angular version 13

Tags: angular, angular13, primeflex

I'm using  "@angular/cli": "~13.3.0",
"primeflex": "^3.1.3",

i've done the installation

```
npm install primeflex --save
```

and then added to angular.json file

```
      "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
```

my Html as follows:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-container yellow-container overflow-hidden">
<div class="flex">
<div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-yellow-500 font-bold text-gray-900 m-2 px-5 py-3 border-round">Prime</div>
<div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-yellow-500 font-bold text-gray-900 m-2 px-5 py-3 border-round">Prime and PrimeFlex</div>
<div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-yellow-500 font-bold text-gray-900 m-2 px-5 py-3 border-round">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
<div class="flex-1 flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-yellow-500 font-bold text-gray-900 m-2 px-5 py-3 border-round">Prime</div>
<div class="flex-1 flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-yellow-500 font-bold text-gray-900 m-2 px-5 py-3 border-round">Prime and PrimeFlex</div>
<div class="flex-1 flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-yellow-500 font-bold text-gray-900 m-2 px-5 py-3 border-round">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

the div align correctly however with no colors and styling as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTrZM.png)

any idea what would be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working but missing a theme, this is why you can see the spacing but no colors

I was stuck for a while and then read on the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/setup) that it does not come with colors, so you need to add a theme, after adding one you can see the colors here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gtnzrg?file=src%2Fstyles.css

added mine on index.css however

Comment: yes you were right I added 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primeflex@3.1.0/themes/saga-blue.css">
to the index.html in the angular project and it worked